# Need an extension for google chrome browser

Tags: chrome, vpn, plug-in

I need an google-chrome-browser extension that let me define my VPN/Cisco connections in it and connect through them in browser.
I'm using Linux Ubuntu and right now I declared my VPN account(I bought from somewhere) including gateway, username and password to connect whole system to internet through VPN account. I'm just wondering if there is any possibility/extension for google chrome browser to do the same in it. so I declare my VPN account in it and just connect my browser through the VPN to internet instead of the whole system.

To make it more clear, below you can see two popular extensions for google chrome browser with predefined servers let you connect your browser to internet through them. I want some thing like these with the ability to define my own VPN server(account)

[Betternet Unlimited Free VPN Proxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/betternet-unlimited-free/gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm?hl=en-US)

[ZenMate VPN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-vpn-best-cyber-se/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme?hl=en-US)

Do you have any suggestion/idea/extension??